# How to disable edit link button bottom of the page for all users except Administrator

Tags: theme-development, post-editor

So I have a website www.chatexplore.com
All of my new users are Editors who can upload images and post.

But I dont want **edit button** at the bottom of the page to be visible to any users except **administrators.**

I tried my users to add/upload media, only editors can do it. So all of my users are editors. So I just want only administrator to see this button.

Answer (score 1):

You should not make users editors if you do not want them to be able to edit any content. IIRC an author role is enough to be able to upload images, and that should probably solve your issue. Otherwise if you need something additional to what authors can do, use a plugin that lets you manipulate user and role permissions (or ask a more specific and detailed question ;) )

Answer (score -2):

Try wrapping the button in a PHP `if` statement that checks if the current user has administrator privelages, like this:

```
<?php if ( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) : ?>

    <a href="#">Your Button</a>

<?php endif; ?>
```

This [Wordpress Codex link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) explains how to check for administrator privileges.

Also, for a 1-liner this is the same thing:

`<?php if ( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) { echo '<a href="#">Button</a>'; } ?>`

**DO NOT USE** `is_admin()` for this [as stated here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin). That function checks if you're in the dashboard, **not** for the privelages you are looking for.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use is_admin function? It checks if your in dashboard and not if current user is admin...

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż You're right! I updated my answer, and Wordpress Codex link.

Comment: First paragraph in linked article says clearly that you SHOULD NOT use current_user_can with roles...